# SprouteCore with WebSockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, protocol-buffers, sproutcore

I'm new to Sproutcore but want to use that framework for building my web application that connects to a WebSocket server to send/receive serialized protobuf binary messages.

Now I want to know how to configure the datasource in Sproutcore to fetch/commit data to the websocket. If anyone has tried something similar, please share.

Appreciate your help !!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recently created an [open-source project](https://github.com/profoundry-us/FireCore) to do this with [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).

Basically, you need to create your [DataSource](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.DataSource&src=false) and override the [fetch](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.DataSource&method=fetch&src=false), [retrieveRecords](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.DataSource&method=retrieveRecords&src=false) and [commitRecords](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.DataSource&method=commitRecords&src=false) methods.

Below is how I did it with Firebase, but you'll definitely need to make modifications to use websockets.

You may also want to checkout the [Thoth](https://github.com/mauritslamers/Thoth) project. It hasn't been updated in a while, but it has quite a bit of code dealing with Socket.IO.

```
sc_require('firebase');

FireCore.DataSource = SC.DataSource.extend({

  _createdIdsToIgnore: [],

  firebaseApp: null,

  firebase: function() {
    var app = this.get('firebaseApp');

    return new Firebase('https://%@.firebaseio.com/'.fmt(app));
  }.property('firebaseApp').cacheable(),

  fetch: function(store, query) {
    var firebase = this.get('firebase'),
        self = this,
        record, type, name, ref, hash, id;

    type = query.get('recordType');
    name = self.firebaseReferenceNameFor(type);
    ref = firebase.child(name);

    /*
     * Detach any existing observers
     */
    ref.off();

    /*
     * Attach our new observers
     */
    ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      self.invokeNext(function() {
        var id = snapshot.name(),
            hash = self.cleanObject(snapshot.val());

        /*
         * Make sure we don't add a record that was
         * just, or is about to be, added by a call
         * to commitRecords.
         */
        if (self._createdIdsToIgnore.contains(id)) {
          self._createdIdsToIgnore.removeObject(id);
        } else {
          store.loadRecord(type, hash, id);
        }
      });
      self.scheduleRunLoop();
    });

    ref.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
      self.invokeNext(function() {
        var id = snapshot.name(),
            hash = self.cleanObject(snapshot.val());

        store.pushRetrieve(type, id, hash);
      });
      self.scheduleRunLoop();
    });

    ref.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
      self.invokeNext(function() {
        var id = snapshot.name();

        store.pushDestroy(type, id);
      });
      self.scheduleRunLoop();
    });

    return YES;
  },

  retrieveRecords: function(store, keys) {
    var firebase = this.get('firebase'),
        self = this,
        type, name, id, hash, status, ref;

    keys.forEach(function(key, index) {
      type = store.recordTypeFor(key);
      name = self.firebaseReferenceNameFor(type);
      id = store.idFor(key);
      ref = firebase.child(name).child(id);

      ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        hash = self.cleanObject(snapshot.val());
        status = store.readStatus(key);

        SC.run(function() {
          if (status == SC.Record.BUSY_LOADING) {
            store.dataSourceDidComplete(key, hash, id);
          } else {
            store.pushRetrieve(type, id, hash);
          }
        });
      });
    });

    return YES;
  },

  commitRecords: function(store, createKeys, updateKeys, destroyKeys, params) {
    var firebase = this.get('firebase'),
        self = this,
        type, name, hash, ref, newRef, id;

    createKeys.forEach(function(key) {
      type = store.recordTypeFor(key);
      name = self.firebaseReferenceNameFor(type);
      hash = self.cleanObject(store.readDataHash(key));
      ref = firebase.child(name);

      // Allow the user to specify an ID (TODO: check the primaryKey field)
      if (hash.guid) {
        newRef = ref.child(hash.guid);
        id = hash.guid;
      } else {
        newRef = ref.push();
        id = newRef.name();
      }

      // Ignore this ID in child_added calls so
      // we don't add it twice
      self._createdIdsToIgnore.pushObject(id);

      // Save the data to firebase
      newRef.set(hash);

      // Then notify the store
      SC.run(function() { store.dataSourceDidComplete(key, hash, id); });
    });

    updateKeys.forEach(function(key) {
      type = store.recordTypeFor(key);
      name = self.firebaseReferenceNameFor(type);
      hash = self.cleanObject(store.readDataHash(key));
      id = store.idFor(key);
      ref = firebase.child(name).child(id);

      ref.set(hash);
      SC.run(function() { store.dataSourceDidComplete(key, hash, id); });
    });

    destroyKeys.forEach(function(key) {
      type = store.recordTypeFor(key);
      id = store.idFor(key);
      name = self.firebaseReferenceNameFor(type);
      ref = firebase.child(name).child(id);

      ref.remove();
      SC.run(function() { store.dataSourceDidDestroy(key); });
    });
  },

  firebaseReferenceNameFor: function(type) {
    return (type.toString().split('.')[1]).decamelize().pluralize();
  },

  scTypeNameFromSnapshot: function(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.ref().path.m[0].camelize().singularize();
  },

  cleanObject: function(object) {
    var self = this,
        type = SC.typeOf(object),
        cleaned = null, key, i, j, tmp;

    if (type == SC.T_OBJECT || type == SC.T_HASH) {
      cleaned = {};

      for (key in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && !key.match(/^_/)) {
          cleaned[key] = self.cleanObject(object[key]);
        }
      }
    } else if (type == SC.T_ARRAY) {
      cleaned = [];

      for (i = 0, j = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        tmp = self.cleanObject(object[i]);

        if (tmp) {
          cleaned[j] = tmp;
          j++;
        }
      }
    } else if (type == SC.T_FUNCTION) {
      // Do nothing, assume that functions should be ignored
    } else {
      cleaned = object;
    }

    return cleaned;
  },

  _scheduleRunLoopTimer: null,
  scheduleRunLoop: function() {
    var self = this;

    if (!this._scheduleRunLoopTimer) {
      SC.RunLoop.begin();
      this._scheduleRunLoopTimer = SC.Timer.schedule({
        target: self,
        action: '_endRunLoop',
        interval: 100
      });
      SC.RunLoop.end();
    }
  },

  _endRunLoop: function() {
    SC.RunLoop.begin(); SC.RunLoop.end();
    this._scheduleRunLoopTimer = null;
  }

});
```

Comment: A higher-level theory addendum to Topher's answer: SC.Store is happy to take "out of band" records, e.g. if you request Person and the data source replies with Person and associated Person, Address, Dog, Job, etc. records. And the data source is doing this from within developer-controlled callback methods. So as long as you're careful with statuses on existing records, you'll use the same process to pipe in new and updated records from a WS-based data source as from a … regular one. (Make sure to check out SC.WebSocket in latest master, too.)

Comment: @Dave, thanks for your reply. I saw the implementation from Nicholas on WS. I have SC version 1.10.2, but the WS support is in 1.11 as far as I know. Where can I get the latest version ?

Comment: @jhari The easiest way to get the latest version of SproutCore is to simply create a `frameworks` directory in your project and clone the SproutCore repo in it. You'll have the latest master branch which may or may not work perfectly, so you may have to checkout a specific commit if you're having trouble.

Comment: @jhari Topher's right and I highly recommend it! It gets you the latest and greatest, and it's very useful to us on the core team to have folks using and testing the latest code and letting us know if something has broken. If you'd rather not live at the edge, v1.11 isn't complete yet but will be available soon. (The benefit of the new SC.WebSocket class is that they handle the Run Loop for you; otherwise you'll have to call SC.run() in your WS event handlers.)

Comment: When I try to build my app in the production mode its failing. The build tool throws, FATAL 23:03:01.006 ~ java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sproutcore/Main (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0) .....what could be the reason ? I ran the build command as follows, sproutcore build my_app. The buildfile under my_app was not edited at all....the app runs fine with sc-server with the debug mode. Appreciate your help on this.